# Join returns multiple results

Tags: t-sql, join

Long night, and I am struggling to fix this problem.

I have a query which returns multiple rows with the same results.

```
SELECT        apf_Members.AppsTitle, apf_Members.AppsFirstName, apf_Members.AppsLastName, vw_apf_MemStat.MemberID, vw_apf_MemStat.DNNUserID, 
                         vw_apf_MemStat.MemStat_LapsedMember, vw_apf_MemStat.MemStat_CurrentMember, vw_apf_MemStat.MemStat_Unrenewed, 
                         apf_Members.MemberID AS Member, apf_Members.PostalCompany AS Company, apf_Members.AppsFirstName AS FirstName, 
                         apf_Members.AppsLastName AS LastName, apf_Members.AppsBirthDate AS DOB, apf_Members.PostalState AS State 

FROM            apf_Members INNER JOIN
                         vw_apf_MemStat ON apf_Members.MemberID = vw_apf_MemStat.MemberID INNER JOIN
                         vw_apf_AttributesConditions ON apf_Members.MemberID = vw_apf_AttributesConditions.MemberID


WHERE        (vw_apf_MemStat.MemStat_CurrentMember <> - 1) AND (vw_apf_AttributesConditions.AttributeID = 7)
ORDER BY apf_Members.AppsLastName, State, apf_Members.MailOption
```

How do I stop duplicate rows?  The columns appear to be exactly the same for each duplicate row, so they are definitely duplicates.

I am assuming it is the 2x inner joins, but I cant seem to fix it.

Thanks Guys,

-R

Comment: can you give sample records? and a screenshot of your result.

Comment: Do you have duplicates in your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the three tables

```
select memberID, count(*) 
  from table 
 group by memberID 
having count(*) > 1
```